# What is the latest Go solution stack name for elasticbeanstalk deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using terraform to create an elastic beanstalk environment and application. The solution stack name seen on the [aws doc website](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-go.html) does not list a solution name for the current time frame [8th September 2020].

Consequently, I keep getting an error `No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.2 running Go 1' found.` when I try to run `terraform apply`.

Also, I am using a module provided by [cloud posse](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment) to get my infrastructure up and running but I doubt that [cloud posse](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment) is at fault here. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Update: Here's the terraform source code to create elastic beasntalk resources.

```
provider aws {
    region = var.region
}

module vpc {
    source     = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-vpc.git?ref=master"
    namespace  = var.namespace
    stage      = var.stage
    name       = var.name
    cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/16"
}

module subnets {
    source               = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-dynamic-subnets.git?ref=master"
    availability_zones   = ["us-east-1a"]
    namespace            = var.namespace
    stage                = var.stage
    name                 = var.name
    vpc_id               = module.vpc.vpc_id
    igw_id               = module.vpc.igw_id
    cidr_block           = module.vpc.vpc_cidr_block
    nat_gateway_enabled  = false
    nat_instance_enabled = false
}

module elastic_beanstalk_application {
    source      = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application.git?ref=master"
    namespace   = var.namespace
    stage       = var.stage
    name        = var.name
    description = "Sentinel Staging"
}

module elastic_beanstalk_environment {
    source                             = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment.git?ref=master"
    namespace                          = var.namespace
    stage                              = var.stage
    name                               = var.name
    description                        = "Test elastic_beanstalk_environment"
    region                             = var.region
    availability_zone_selector         = "Any 2"
    dns_zone_id                        = var.dns_zone_id
    elastic_beanstalk_application_name = module.elastic_beanstalk_application.elastic_beanstalk_application_name

    instance_type           = "t3.small"
    autoscale_min           = 1
    autoscale_max           = 2
    updating_min_in_service = 0
    updating_max_batch      = 1

    loadbalancer_type       = "application"
    vpc_id                  = module.vpc.vpc_id
    loadbalancer_subnets    = module.subnets.public_subnet_ids
    application_subnets     = module.subnets.public_subnet_ids
    allowed_security_groups = [module.vpc.vpc_default_security_group_id]

    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.docker
    solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.2 running Go 1"

    additional_settings = [
      {
        namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        name      = "DB_URI"
        value     = var.db_uri
      },
      {
        namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        name      = "USER"
        value     = var.user
      },
      {
        namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        name      = "PASSWORD"
        value     = var.password
      },
      {
        namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        name      = "PORT"
        value     = "5000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And here's the exact error taken from the console when I try `terraform apply` with suitable variables passed as command line arguments.

```
module.subnets.aws_network_acl.public[0]: Refreshing state... [id=acl-0a62395908205c288]
module.subnets.data.aws_availability_zones.available[0]: Reading... [id=2020-09-07 06:34:08.002137232 +0000 UTC]
module.subnets.data.aws_availability_zones.available[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=2020-09-07 06:34:12.416467455 +0000 UTC]
module.elastic_beanstalk_environment.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.default: Creating...

Error: InvalidParameterValue: No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.2 running Go 1' found.
    status code: 400, request id: 631d5204-f667-4355-aa65-d617536a00b7

  on .terraform/modules/elastic_beanstalk_environment/main.tf line 505, in resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default":
 505: resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
```

Comment: The current go platform version is listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.go), not in your link. But `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.2 running Go 1` is the latest version. Can you provide more contextual info about your terraform code. Your stack name should be correct.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I have updated the question with relevant code. Please let me know if you need anything else to help me analyse the problem.